# CSS3 transition trigger not working

Tags: css, tumblr

Im trying to make a situation where, when one element is hovered over, a different element is transitioned. I typically use the exact code as below and it works fine, but somethings wrong this time around apparantly.

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    padding:10px;
    left:0px;
    background:#fff;
    font-style:none;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s;
        transition: width 2s;
    z-index:1;

}

#sideimage {
    max-width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #111;
    position: absolute;
    top: 290px;
    left: 25%;
    }

#sideimage:hover #sidebar {
    width: 700px;
}
```

If anybody can tell me what I'm doing wrong or give me another solution, that'd be very much appreciated.

[Link to the page](http://holdtheblind.tumblr.com/tagged/manga)

Comment: #sidebar is the parent of #sideimage! In your last selector, the parent node should be on the left of spaces where children on the right. Anyway even if you change the order it won't work. I think you should take advantage of jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1):

Well your css doesn't make much sense.
`#sideimage` is a child of `#sidebar` so `#sideimage:hover #sidebar` won't ever work.
You cannot change a parent element based on a child's event without javascript.
You should give us more details on what you are trying to achieve exactly.